# Why does this javascript/jQuery JSON parsing code not work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, datepicker

Here is my jQuery code. It should parse the json returned by [this](http://www.fifteenthedigey.co.uk/dates/jsondates.php) php script. The php is known to work. It should also convert the date literals to a javascript date object. However, an error occurs at `dates.length`. Can anyone see what is wrong with the code?

```
if($("#calendar").length)
{
    var dates;
    $.post("/dates/jsondates.php",function(data)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            data[i].start = new Date(data[i].start);
            data[i].end = new Date(data[i].end);
        }
        dates = data;
    }, "json");

    $("#calendar").datepicker(
    {
        beforeShowDay: function(date)
        {
            for(var i=0; i<dates.length; i++)
            {
                if(dates[i].start<date<dates[i].end)
                {
                    return new Array(0, "booked", dates[i].comment);
                }
            }
            return new Array(1);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datepicker code will (potentially) be getting executed before the ajax call completes. At the minimum, try moving the datepicker portion of the code into the $.post callback:-

```
if ($("#calendar").length)
{
    var dates;
    $.post("/dates/jsondates.php",function(data)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
                data[i].start = new Date(data[i].start);
                data[i].end = new Date(data[i].end);
        }
        dates = data;

        $("#calendar").datepicker(
        {
            beforeShowDay: function(date)
            {
                    for(var i=0; i<dates.length; i++)
                    {
                            if(dates[i].start<date<dates[i].end)
                            {
                                    return new Array(0, "booked", dates[i].comment);
                            }
                    }
                    return new Array(1);
            }
        });
    }, "json");

}
```

Edit: As an aside, and if it was me, I'd probably split it up into some sort of caller function to get the date data and feed it a callback. E.g:-

```
function __callDateController(callback)
{
    $.post("/dates/jsondates.php",function(data)
    {
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        {
            data[i].start = new Date(data[i].start);
            data[i].end = new Date(data[i].end);
        }

        if (callback !== undefined) {
            callback(data);
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

And then feed it a callback for your date picker to deal with:-

```
__callDateController(function(dates)
{
    $("#calendar").datepicker(
        {
            beforeShowDay: function(date)
            {
                for(var i=0; i<dates.length; i++)
                {
                    if(dates[i].start<date<dates[i].end)
                    {
                        return new Array(0, "booked", dates[i].comment);
                    }
                }
                return new Array(1);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your calendar datepicker code is executing before the AJAX is done processing.

Your datePicker code needs to go inside the $.post callback function, beneath the for loop, and beneath the line `dates = data;`